# How could I generate random coefficients for polynomials using Sum( f(x), (x,0,b) )?

Tags: sympy

```
from sympy import Sum, Eq
from sympy.abc import n,x
import random
def polynomial(x):
    i = 0
    def random_value(i):
        return random.choice([i for i in range(-10,10) if i not in [0]])
    eq = Sum(random_value(i)*x**n, (n,0,random_value(i)))
    display(Eq(eq,eq.doit(), evaluate=False))

polynomial(x)
polynomial(x)
```

With this code, the coefficients are always the same.

Also, I am not sure if the algebra evaluations are correct for b < 0 .

Comment: I know OP asked to use `sum` but for the lost reader (like me) that founds themselves wanting a simple random polynomial there is an in-built way of doing this using `random_poly`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76554637/generate-a-random-polynomial-using-sympy

Comment: random_poly breaks when you are heavily manipulating the generated equations or substituting other equations for the variables. Like converting x+5 to (x^2+3) +5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `IndexedBase` to generate symbolic-placeholder coefficients, and then substitute them with numerical coefficients.

```py
from sympy import Sum, Eq, Matrix, IndexedBase
from sympy.abc import n, x
import random
def polynomial(x):
    # n will go from zero to this positive value
    to = random.randint(0, 10)
    # generate random coefficients
    # It is important for them to be a sympy Matrix or Tuple,
    # otherwise the substitution (later step) won't work
    coeff = Matrix([random.randint(-10, 10) for i in range(to + 1)])
    c = IndexedBase("c")
    eq = Sum(c[n]*x**n, (n, 0, to)).doit()
    eq = eq.subs(c, coeff)
    return eq

display(polynomial(x))
display(polynomial(x))
```

Another ways is to avoid using `Sum`, relying instead on list-comprehension syntax and builtin `sum`:

```py
def polynomial(x):
    to = random.randint(0, 10)
    coeff = [random.randint(-10, 10) for i in range(to + 1)]
    return sum([c * x**n for c, n in zip(coeff, range(to + 1))])

display(polynomial(x))
display(polynomial(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of coefficients (with highest order coefficient first and constant last) directly to Poly and then convert that to an expression:

```py
>>> from sympy import Poly
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> Poly([1,2,3,4], x)
Poly(x**3 + 2*x**2 + 3*x + 4, x, domain='ZZ')
>>> _.as_expr()
x**3 + 2*x**2 + 3*x + 4

>>> from random import randint, choice
>>> Poly([choice((-1,1))*randint(1,10) for i in range(randint(0, 10))], x).as_expr()
-3*x**4 + 3*x**3 - x**2 - 6*x + 2
```