# Generate a random polynomial using Sympy

Tags: sympy, polynomials

I'd like to generate a polynomial of a random degree with random coefficients using `sympy`.

If possible, I'd also like to control the percentage of coefficients that are zero. I know that something similar is possible for Matrices using `randMatrix`.

Comment: I found this post but, the answer is not quite what I am looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73341816/how-could-i-generate-random-coefficients-for-polynomials-using-sum-fx-x-0-b

Answer (score 1):

I found the following in-built method.

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.specialpolys.random_poly

A random polynomial of degree at most 5 with integer coefficient between -10 and 10.

```
from sympy.polys.specialpolys import random_poly
from sympy abc import x
from random import randint

n = randint(0,5)
p = random_poly(x,n,-10,10)
```

But ultimately, I ended up writing my own to control the percentage.

Answer (score 1):

You have already posted how to generate a random polynomial. Sadly there's no built-in option to control the percentage of zero coefficients. But you can control them like this:

```
from sympy.polys.specialpolys import random_poly
from sympy.abc import x
import random
from random import randint

degree = randint(0,5)
zero_percentage = 0.3

poly = random_poly(x, degree, -10, 10, polys=True)

coefficients = poly.all_coeffs()  # get all the coefficients of the polynomial

zero_count = int(len(coefficients) * zero_percentage)
zero_indices = random.sample(range(len(coefficients)), zero_count)
for i in zero_indices:
    coefficients[i] = 0

modified_poly = sum(coefficients[i] * x**i for i in range(len(coefficients)))  # construct the modified polynomial

print(modified_poly)
```

Comment: This generates coefficients with a 0.3 probability of being zero. This is not the beheaviour that I'm looking for. I want 30% of the coefficients to be zero and 70% are non-zero. Also, the polynomial is not of degree 5 every time, which might be undesired in some situations (for me), but not others. It is easy to handle this separately :)

Comment: I think I'm missing something. What's the difference between your first two sentences? You mean some of the coefficient might be already zero from `random_poly`?
Edit; AH! I see, it's only a propability, not a certainty. I'll update my answer.